# What does decimate mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is caption of a post from [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/01/30/world/europe/wagner-convict-ukraine-russia.html?searchResultPosition=2):

> Tens of thousands of inmates have joined a mercenary group fighting with the Kremlin’s decimated forces in Ukraine. Some of them are returning to civilian life with military training and, in many cases, battlefield traumas.

As I know, *decimated* means heavily damaged. So does the phrase *Kremlin's decimated forces in Ukraine* mean forces in which were heavily damaged in the Ukraine?

Comment: *So does the phrase Kremlin's decimated forces in Ukraine mean forces in which were heavily damaged in the Ukraine?* Since you know what decimated means and are correct in your interpretation, I wonder why you are posting here. Is there something you are confused about or we can help you with?

Comment: It's not explicit that the forces were decimated *in Ukraine*, but given current circumstances the writer probably assumes that this will be our understanding.

Comment: @ralph.m The quote is from the summary of the article. The rest of the article makes the context clear.

Comment: @StuartF Actually I wasn't really sure about my interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I know, decimated means heavily damaged.

Originally, it meant reduced in number by 10% by execution. Today, it means heavily reduced by adverse action or circumstances.

OED

> 1.c. transitive. More generally: to reduce drastically or severely; to destroy, ruin, devastate.
>
> *This use has sometimes been criticized on etymological grounds (see, for example, M. West & P. F. Kimber Deskbk. Correct Eng. (1957) 119 and quot. 1944), but is now the most usual sense in standard English.*

1957   J. Bishop Day Christ Died (1959) 81   They had been secretly certain that, when the time of trial arrived, Jesus would summon legions of avenging angels who would decimate his enemies.

2013   Leicester Mercury (Nexis) 9 July 6   Leicester Homelessness Council spokesman..said: ‘I think it [sc. the reduction in the number of hostel beds] will totally decimate the services.’

Thus *the Kremlin’s decimated forces* = the Kremlin’s forces that have been heavily reduced in number (by Ukrainian forces).